# Hibernate JOIN of Unrelated Entities Out of Scope in the Generated SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, hql

Since *Hibernate 5.1*, it started to offer the feature for us to join two unrelated entities as we do in native SQL. It is a fantastic feature! However, I recently encountered an **unexpected** behavior of this feature. I had a query with mixed *JOINs (Left Joins and Inner Joins)* with both *related* entities and *unrelated* entities. In the generated SQL, all of the *unrelated* entities JOINs are place in the bottom of the query, which caused this exception:
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier "tlterm6_.term_id" could not be bound.`

I'm baffled about how that happened and why was the feature implemented in that way (They must have a good explanation, but I have not found any solutions or explanations online yet).

Does anyone have an idea of a *workaround* or how to fix that?

The application is running on Hibernate 5.4.6 and SQL Server database.

Sample Entity Definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
Public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String first_name;

    @Column
    private String first_name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<College> colleges = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...Other details and getters/setters omitted
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "college")
Public class College implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;

    // ...Other details and getters/setters omitted
}
```

Example:

```
FROM Student student
JOIN Class clazz ON student.id = clazz.student_id
JOIN student.colleges college
```

Generated SQL:

```
FROM dbo.student AS student
INNER JOIN dbo.college AS college ON student.id = college.student_id
INNER JOIN dbo.class AS clazz ON student.id = clazz.student_id
```

The expected generated SQL should be following the same order of the JOINs, however, it places the **Related/Mapped** entities Joins to the top and moves the **Unrelated/Unmapped** entities Joins to the bottom.

Comment: Will left join be a problem here? If not try using left join.

Comment: @saifulislamplabon Left Join has the same issue :(

Comment: can you share your entity definitions?

Comment: @saifulislamplabon I just edited the post to include the two entity definitions :D

Comment: I am trying to understand where the `tlterm6_.term_id1 came from. Maybe it is in the `Class` entity?

Comment: @saifulislamplabon That is from the generated SQL in my real project. The error message was to inform me that the table could not be bound b/c it's out of the scope due to the order of the generated SQL. It groups related/mapped entities to the top and move all of the unrelated/unmapped entities to the bottom causing that error.